# didReceiveMemoryWarning is not getting called -- UITabBarViewController Application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, didreceivememorywarning

My application is a tab bar based applcation including 6 tabs in it. When I receive a memory warning all 5 view controllers `didReceiveMemoryWarning` methods are getting called, except for 1 view controller. So I registered for UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification in that view controller like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(didReceiveMemoryWarning)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification  
                                               object:nil];
```

However, this view controller's `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method is not called. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that after having called enough memory warnng methods, enough memory is freed so it do not call other anymore. As this may be called, or not, for other running apps. It may not call everybody to release data if enough data has already been released.

Comment: But my application is still crashing.

Comment: @Dee : what about that crash ? Where does it crash ? You didn't talk about that...

Comment: I have to attach 3 images to an email. So when I continuously do that action it is crashing. Size of the images are like this: 2 images are of {700,385} size & the 3rd one is {768 × 2933}.

Comment: @Dee: This is another question. End this one, and open another.